# VueJS - dynamic function name inside methods

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a list and navigation that is generated with 12 items/page based on the number of data rows.

My navigation buttons trigger vue-js v-on:click events

I'm trying to generate the function methods in the JS file dynamically as well but can not seem to put in a loop statement within the method section. Keep getting syntax errors.

Is there a particular JS syntax within the vueJS method section?

```
        methods: {

        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++){
            featuredStores.'x' = function(){
                 for (y = 0; y < 2; y++)
                this.storeFeatNav.'y' = !this.storeFeatNav.'y'
        }}
```

I'm also using Laravel framework if that helps.

Thank you

Comment: it seems `this.storeFeatNav[x]`

Comment: @Sphinx - didn't seem to work. I get bogged down even at the for statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that you want to add methods dynamically but it's not clear what you are doing in your dynamic method attachment code. So, I'm going to show you a way to add methods dynamically, for example:

```js
var methods = {
    greet() {
        console.log(this.message + ' from greet method.');
    }
};

for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++)  {
    methods['featuredStores'+x] = function() {
        console.log(this.message + ' from featuredStores'+x+' method.');
    }
}
```

Notice that, the `methods['featuredStores'+x]` is actually making the method name by concatenating the value of `x` with string `featuredStores` inside the loop so the first time the value of `x` is `0` which produces `featuredStores0` and second time the value of `x` is `1` so it's producing `featuredStores0` and finally you have three methods which are:

```js
greet // hard coded
featuredStores0 // added dynamically within the loop
featuredStores1 // added dynamically within the loop
```

Now, all you need to add the `methods` object as a property of the new instance when creating the `Vue` instance, for example:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    methods: methods, // or just methods
    data:{
        message: "Hello World"
    }
});
```

To see it in action, please run the following code snippet (Hope this will give you some idea):

```js
var methods = {
    greet() {
        console.log(this.message + ' from greet method.');
    }
};

for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++)  {
    methods['featuredStores'+x] = function() {
        console.log(this.message + ' from featuredStores'+x+' method.');
    }
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    methods,
    data:{
        message: "Hello World"
    },
    created() {
     this.greet();
        this.featuredStores0();
 this.featuredStores1();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.8.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @The Alpha, thank  you for taking time and understand my question. This solution is exactly what I am looking for. Best of all, I've learned how to ask my questions better in this forum

Comment: Welcome! Glad to know that :-)